# How to change variable values between namespaces / classes?

Tags: forms, class

I have a main form with a textBox1 with string value : asd

```
namespace Crystal
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
       //here is a textBox1 with text "asd"
    }
}
```

I want to change this textBox1 text from this class:

```
namespace Crystal.Utilities
{
   public class Logging
   {
       //textBox1.Text = "dsa";
   }
}
```

The problem is, I cant change the value of textBox1 from the Logging class, because it doesnt exists there :/ How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't need to expose the entire TextBox - Don't want others to mess with other things than just the text, and I think it's more readable and simple to just call a method that does that, instead of accessing the TextBox directly.

```
namespace Crystal
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
       public void setTextBox1Text(string newText)
       {
        TextBox1.Text=newText
       }
    }
}
```

namespace Crystal.Utilities
{
   public class Logging
   {
       mainForm.SetTextBox1Text("new text");
   }
}

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a public property (supposing you're writing C#) or a method. Then access it from the other place.

```
namespace Crystal
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        //here is a textBox1 with text "asd"

        public TextBox MyTextBox {
            get { return textBox1; }
        }
    }
}


namespace Crystal.Utilities
{
   public class Logging
   {
       var foo = MainForm; // Get an instance of your MainForm here somehow.
       foo.MyTextBox.Text = "dsa";
   }
}
```

Comment: Your *MainForm* class is partial. There is source code for it in 2 places. Use right click > View code.